# How to add a yearly exception inside a MPP using VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, project, ms-project, mpp

I expect the code to be similar to the question here:
[Insert exceptions into Resource Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70794737/insert-exceptions-into-resource-calendar)

From the MPP interface you just select the "yearly" radio button and set the day and month in which the exception (day off work) will be repeated, but I need to do it with from developer mode code to expand the functionality later.

I tried using the Type 2 property for:
pjYearlyMonthDay    2   The exception recurrence pattern is yearly on a specified day of a month, for example on December 24.

```
Dim CalName As String
CalName = ActiveProject.Calendar.Name
ActiveProject.BaseCalendars(CalName).Exceptions.Add Type:=2, Start:="5/01/2023", Occurrences:=10, Name:="TEST", MonthDay:="5 January"
```

But I have error 1101.
Microsoft documentation here but I can't figure it out:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.exceptions.add
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.pjexceptiontype

Comment: Why are you ignoring the accepted answer in your linked question? They mentioned to use the `Resources(CalName).Calendar` property, have you given that a go?

Comment: @Notus_Panda On the contrary, the OP used that accepted answer as a guide to solving their problem but got stuck because the exception types in the two posts are different. Also, the focus of the linked post was the difference between resource calendars and project calendars.

Comment: `.BaseCalendars(CalName).Exceptions.Add` isn't what you had in the answer then: `.Resources("Joe Bloggs").Calendar.Exceptions.Add` , figured the problem lied there hence my comment. Regardless, as long as the OP gets to solve his problem, that's all that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax for adding this kind of yearly exception:

```
ActiveProject.Calendar.Exceptions.Add Type:=2 _
    , Start:="05/01/2023", Occurrences:=10, Name:="TEST", Month:=1, MonthDay:=5
```

The Month and MonthDay parameters need to be set and they are both Long. See [Exceptions.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.exceptions.add) method.

Comment: No need to use the calendar name anymore of the referred resource?

Comment: This question is not about resources.